# After updating spring boot version from 2.5.6 to 3.0.11 throws error sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I have update my application's spring boot version from 2.5.6 to 3.0.11. After updating all the required dependencies. When running the spring the spring boot application I receive the following error.

```
database_name - LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean [ERROR] Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PostInitCallback queue could not be processed...
database_name - PostInitCallbackEntry - Entity(com.package.model.MyEntity) `sqmMultiTableInsertStrategy` interpretation
```

**Note: We cannot delete the previous database and recreate it as there is a lot of data and do not want data loss. If we do delete the previous database then it does not throw the same error.**

Here is what MyEntity class looks like:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Inheritance;
import jakarta.persistence.InheritanceType;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "uniqueConstraintName", columnNames = { "column1", "column2",
                "column3", "column4" })

})
public abstract class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String column1;
    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String column2;
    @Column(length = 15)
    private String column3 = null;
    @Column(length = 25)
    private String column4;
    private String column5;
    private String column6;
}
```

I have also tried after adding a dialect for the database which looks something like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

But facing the same issue.

Here is what the pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11</version>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>application_name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>application_name</name>
    <description>Application Description</description>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hazelcast for caching -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JAXB API only -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    
      <!-- JAXB Implementation -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.952</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.secretsmanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-secretsmanager-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone provide a solution or explain where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you read the upgrade guides from 2.5.X to 2.6.X and from 2.6.x to 2.7.X and from 2.7.X to 3.X https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki